# Retrieve email body from SNS bounce Notification

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-sns, amazon-ses

I am sending an email using ses and if there is any bounce I am using SNS topic and SQS to capture the bounce notification but I couldn't see the email body in bounce notification .I can see sender email, recipient email , subject , content-type but couldn't see the body .
Any suggestions how can I retrieve the email body

I have done research but couldn't find where I can get the email body of bounced notifications

Comment: An email message could be multiple MB worth of data which won't fit into an SNS or SQS message.  You'll need to store the body you send in a DB of some sort and reference it by, perhaps, the "to" address.